# Function call as a default function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having

```
# example.py

def foo(arg=bar()):
        pass
```

will execute `bar` even  with `from example import foo`.

I remember that long time ago I saw something like:

```
# example.py

def foo(arg=lambda: bar()):
        pass
```

but I'm not sure if it's the best way and now, when I am stuck with this, I can't find any info on how to deal with this behaviour.

What is the correct way to have function call as a default function argument in python?

Comment: In which situations do you want the function bound to `arg` called?  When `foo` is imported?  When `foo` is called?  Other times?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, when it is called. I found wim answer what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the most Pythonic way:

```
def foo(arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        arg = bar()
    ...
```

If you want the function `bar` to be called only once, and you don't want it to be called at import time, then you will have to maintain that state *somewhere*.  Perhaps in a callable class:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.default_arg = None

    def __call__(self, arg=None):
        if arg is None:
            if self.default_arg is None:
                self.default_arg = bar()
            arg = self.default_arg
        ...

foo = Foo()
```